# Python push single file into android device with different names until the device runs out of memory

Tags: python

I know "adb push" command could be used to push files to android device. But in Python how do i push single file for example file.txt(size of about 50 KB) into android sdcard with different names(for ex. file1.txt, file2.txt etc) until the device storage is full. Any idea much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative solution to this problem. In a python while loop push a single file into SD Card and use "adb mv" to rename the file in the SD Card after pushing the file, continue this until the device memory is full.

Comment: How did you push the files using python? Please post your code. Thanks.